# Reporting Services 2008R2 throws "native compiler error [BC30494] Line is too long."

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

```
An unexpected error occurred while compiling expressions. Native compiler return value: '[BC30494] Line is too long.'.
```

When RS throws this error, the typical scenario appears to be that there are too many text boxes on a specific data region; and the only known measure seems to be to 'minify' text box names (ie. rename TextBox345 to T345).

My report is not *that* large (<100 text boxes); but I make extensive use of the Lookup() function to set many of the textbox style properties from a styles dataset (>2500 Lookup() calls).

So my guess is that the VB code-behind that gets generated for the Lookup() function is quite verbose and therefore breaks the 64K limit for a generated VB code block per data region.

1. Can I test my hypothesis? Ie. is there a way I can inspect the generated VB code?
2. Any suggestions as to how to fix/dodge this problem? *Needless to say that using abbreviated names in my case didn't cut it.*

Answer (score 0):

Quite a delayed response but for the sake of posterity:

1. The .vb source file of the generated code exists on disk temporarily within the directory `C:\Users\{RS Service Account Name}\AppData\Local\Temp`. As you mentioned, if any line goes past 65535 characters then it will fail compilation [due to a VB limitation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdzat713.aspx)
2. This issue was just fixed in Reporting Services 2012 SP2 CU5; the KB article is located [here](http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3038267). Unfortunately mainstream support for SQL 2008 R2 [has ended](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlreleaseservices/archive/2014/07/09/end-of-mainstream-support-for-sql-server-2008-and-sql-server-2008-r2.aspx) so the fix is unlikely to be backported. As for workarounds:

   - Shorten the textbox names to the absolute minimum possible (e.g., use all possible single character names, then all possible two character names)
   - Try using subreports to split up the report
   - Try to rework your dataset query so that you can reduce the Lookup() calls